How to add adsense to Kotlin mutiplatform (KMM) web app?
I want to menotize my webapp which i created on kotlin multiplatform(KMM) and for web apps i feel adsense is best but i am unable to find a proper solution how to integrate adsense to a webapp built in KMM
I tried to check a solution to integrate Adsense in webapp built with KMM but was unable to find one so if anybody has solution it would be a great help.
